# Is there a way of summing specific columns if they exist in a list?

Tags: python, pandas, list, sum, lookup

I'm trying to lookup a column in df2 and only sum the columns in df1 that exist in the df2 column

```py
df1 =
London, New York, Paris, LA, Chicago
1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 3000

df2 =
US Cities
New York
Miami
LA
Chicago
Seattle
```

result:

```py
df1 =
London, New York, Paris, LA, Chicago, Sum of US Cities
1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 3000, 15000
```

Comment: You forgot to include your current code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```py
df1['Sum of US Cities'] = df1.loc[:, df1.columns.isin(df2['US Cities'])].sum(axis=1)
```

Output

```
   London  New York  Paris     LA  Chicago  Sum of US Cities
0    1000      2000   5000  10000     3000             15000
```